# Windows XP Search Engine

Tags: windows, windows-xp

ASK.com has completely taken over and is a real pain in the ass.

How can I get rid of this of software, it keeps popping up when I don't want it. Add/Remove software doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried their official uninstall instructions? <http://about.ask.com/apn/toolbar/docs/default/faq/en/ie/index.html#na4

Answer (score 0):

Well, here there are a couple of options you can choose. If the toolbar is running as a separate process, then look for it in Task Manager and note down the name and path to the file on your storage device.

The first thing you should do is try and go in to your browser's settings and disable the Browser Helper Object or add-on. If this does not work and the software is actually a separate process, then you could force-delete the file using software called FileAssassin. It's available through the [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) website, who make the Malwarebytes anti-malware scanner.

The basic premise of using FileAssassin is that it uses specialist methods to kill the file you want to delete, then deletes it. Remember the name of the toolbar in Task Manager? Find the file again in the dialog box.[image: Shows the interface of FileAssassin]

Then, execute the action and the file should be deleted. Re-open your browser and see if the toolbar is there. If it is still there, then download Malwarebytes and check everything in the options, then run a full scan. It should pick up the files. Delete those, then you should be home and dry.

NB: I take no responsibility for any damage you may cause to your system. Do this at your own risk.